# Mobilefirst 8.0 Push notification Implemantation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have made simple application using Ionic and cordova. Added Mobilefirst plugin in it. Also I have used security adapters in it ResourceAdapter and UserLogin Adapter which is provided by IBM.
Now I want to include push notification part in this project. So I have added push notificationMFP plugin in same project. Sender id and key in push settings. Added scope push.mobileclient also.

When I tried to call MFPPush.registerDevice javascript method I am getting failed to register device.

```
Failed to register device:"com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException: Response: Status=404, Text: Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404\n, Error Message: Not Found"
```

Also when App get initialized I can see in MFP console that particular device in devices list and when I login I can see user ID also get added in device information. So what is problem is something I am missing? Why device is not able to register for push?

Comment: Is this for Cordova iOS or Android? It'll be easier if you will provide your project for debugging, there is no way to be sure you configured this correctly without testing it.

Comment: @IdanAdar Add android platform and please let me know what wrong I am doing.

Comment: @IdanAdar Have you checked the code?

Comment: Are you sure you have properly registered the app in the server? did you use the correct version number as seen in the config.xml file?

Comment: @IdanAdar Yes.Now its working Its initialization issue. Just got it. Thnks. One more help I need. I am trying to send notification to particular User ID through MFP console. But device can not get any notification. But i cn see User ID against device id. So there is option to send to user id in console. But its not working for me

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the server log and client log (logcat) so we can determine why the notification did not reach the device

Answer (score 0):

The original issue in the question was resolved:

> Yes. Now its working Its initialization issue. Just got it. Thnks.

The user then added a new issue via comments:

> One more help I need. I am trying to send notification to particular User ID through MFP console. But device can not get any notification. But i cn see User ID against device id. So there is option to send to user id in console. But its not working for me

Unless you got an error in the console, this means that the notification in all likelyhood left the MobileFirst Server. From there there are numerous options why the sending will fail. [See the Push Notifications Troubleshooting section](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/troubleshooting/notifications/).